# Camel routes to resume/start Activiti task with variables

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activiti

I have setup spring boot with activiti and camel. I am trying to configure Camel routes to poll email to do the below. Some examples on the same would be really helpful:

- Resume a activti task
- Start a activiti task

For e.g. to resume a user task we need to pass something like the below to Acitviti Rest API which works fine

```
{"action" : "complete", "variables": [ {"name":"id, "value":1}, {"name":"outcome", "value":true} ]}
```

I started with the below for setting up Camel Routes, but not sure how to add variables that needs to be passed into activiti process:

```
@Component
public class MyCamelMailRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("imaps://imap.server.com?username=myemail@example.com&password=xxxxxx&consumer.delay=60000"
                + "&searchTerm.subject=Approving&searchTerm.unseen=true")
                .to("activiti:activationProcess:approval");
    }
}
```

Here are my maven dependencies

```
<properties>
    <activiti.version>5.22.0</activiti.version>
    <activiti.rest.version>5.17.0</activiti.rest.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sony.spe.spt</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpm-services-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.rest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel - start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Camel - end -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The above throws the below exception during spring boot startup, going by few references from various google searches revealed that I could direct to activiti using the notation I have used but as the error points it is not there by default. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[activiti:activationProcess:approval] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[imaps://imap.server.com?username=myemail@... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: activiti://activationProcess:approval due to: No component found with scheme: activiti
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:124) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:41) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.workflow.WorkflowApplication.main(WorkflowApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[activiti:activationProcess:approval] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[imaps://imap.server.com?username=myemail@... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: activiti://activationProcess:approval due to: No component found with scheme: activiti
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1071) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:984) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3401) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3132) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:183) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2961) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2980) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2924) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.maybeStart(RoutesCollector.java:141) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:116) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: activiti://activationProcess:approval due to: No component found with scheme: activiti
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:629) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:108) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:114) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:545) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:506) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:222) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1068) ~[camel-core-2.18.3.jar:2.18.3]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JAR / maven dependency of the activiti-camel component. Its not from Apache Camel but from the Activiti project so look there what the dependency is named.

You can see that from the last stacktrace saying the component is not found.

Comment: Thanks!! that did the trick, was missing the dependency, I thought the spring-boot activiti dependencies would have automatically included it as I already had the camel dependencies in their.

But, do you have any pointers on how to pass variables?

Comment: Check the activiti documentation. I dont know this component. I work primary with the Apache Camel project at ASF not activiti